# How to Create Auto Increment Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint

I want create auto increment ID in SharePoint and ID should be in the form 0000, 0001, ..., 0010, 0012 etc. With 4 digits include increment number using calculated value in column SharePoint list

Comment: Is this column used from id=1?What do you need when column count>9999?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a calculated column,and add this formula:

```
=RIGHT(CONCATENATE("0000",ID),4)
```

Test result:
[image]